# Box divided by border

Tags: css

Hey guys how can I make the border inside divide the box, but the gradient to be in the first one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTHT.png 
My code:https://jsfiddle.net/ivailo/1hx4axpt/1/

```
.parent2{
height:256px;
width: 202px;
border: 1px solid #E18728;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(185,219,105,1) 44%,rgba(209,211,172,1) 80%);
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: I want to make this white border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, the top of your box possess a border, in this case, create a child div and apply the gradient background to it. So for the html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

And for the CSS part :

```
.parent {
    height:256px;
    width: 202px;
    border: 1px solid #E18728;
    border-radius:5px;
  background-color: rgba(209,211,172,1);
}

.child {
  height:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(185,219,105,1) 44%,rgba(209,211,172,1) 80%);
  border-radius:5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pseudo element, like `::before`

```css
.parent2 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 202px;
  border: 1px solid #E18728;
  background: rgba(209, 211, 172, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.parent2::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(185, 219, 105, 1) 44%, rgba(209, 211, 172, 1) 80%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent2">
</div>
```